# play a song from a URL in BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

In my BlackBerry application, I have a radiotime URL of a song.  The song may be in mp3 or mms format. How can I play it from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIM has docs that explain this: [Play audio in a BlackBerry device application](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Play_audio_in_a_BB_device_app_1222359_11.jsp)

You can also find a solution on the blackberry suportforums: [Questions about playing short mp3](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/2-Questions-about-playing-short-mp3/m-p/103153?query.id=296523#M11616)